# Show App Icon in View with Opened Apps on Android

Tags: android, icons

i created a new Project with Android Studio, created a new Image Asset of the App Icon. The Icons have been saved in the mipmap folders, not as i'm used to in the drawables.

Now ia can use the App Icon as my Icon in the ActionBar etc. but when i open the view on my Smartphone which shows all running programs (dont know how this View is called) it uses the standars Android Icon, not the Icon i set.

How can i make sure that it uses my App Icon everywhere?

My AndroidManifest:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label=" Pentle" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set the new icon in your Manifest in the `<Applicaton>` tag.

It should be something like this

```
<Application
  android:icon="@drawable/your_image"
  .... />
```

Comment: I can't create an image asset for drawables, only for mipmap therefor i use `android:icon="@mipmap/logo"
        android:logo="@mipmap/logo"`

Comment: but can you confirm that you are pointing to the correct image? Also check that you have the same image in all mipmap folders (hdpi, lpdi, mdpi, ...)

Comment: Yes, the icon shows propely in my ActionBar and my AppDrawer, but not in the view which shows all running applications nor the intallation procedure.

Comment: Try uninstalling (completely) the app and install it again. It might be an issue with your launcher.

Comment: Tried it, didnt help. It worked in previous apps i created, but not in this one... maybe because it uses mipmap and not drawable?

Comment: That is also possible, as mine works just the way I told you. Only the icon is set and I see it everywhere

Comment: Which leads my to my next Question: how can i save my pics in the drawable? Creating an image asset on "res" it doesnt give me any option to save it in the drawable, tried all options, same when i try to create an image asset on "drawable"....

Comment: I am not sure I understand this question, but all my images are in the drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi and others. http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: It doesnt show the app icon in the list of currently running projects, but everywhere else...